# qt equivalent for docking control to it's container in winforms

Tags: qt

I'm trying out qt creator lately and i hate reading hours of docs and tutorials just for doing simple tasks.

So, in winforms i can drag & drop a control from toolbox and set the dock property so it automatically maximizes itself to it's container's size.

What is the equivalent of this behaviour in qt?

I googled this and found it strange that nobody wondered the same before.

Comment: I guess that the reading part is most important with qt. They have really good documentation site. Without reading it's a no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences between the concepts of WinForms and Qt. You need to study the concept of layouts. Take a look at the relevant part of the documentation of Qt Designer: Using [Layouts in Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html)

> Before a form can be used, the objects on the form need to be placed
>   into layouts. This ensures that the objects will be displayed properly
>   when the form is previewed or used in an application. Placing objects
>   in a layout also ensures that they will be resized correctly when the
>   form is resized.

Answer (score 0):

Qt uses [layouts](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html). Add QHBoxLayout or QVBoxLayout to the parent widget.